# How to get the input action which is performing?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input-buffer

I'm learning the new input system and I'm looking for something like this:

```
if(anyInputActionIsPerformed)
{
return thatInputAction;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the name of the current input action so I can save it in my input buffer for triggering something later.

Comment: Ok guys I've figured it out from the documentation, I found the "InputActionMap.actionTriggered" event which is perfect enough for me so if anyone else bumped into a similar problem, you might wanna try this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IsPressed` directly:

```
_controls.ActionMap.Action.IsPressed()
```

For Example:

```cs
private PlayerControls _controls;
public void Start()
{
    _controls = new PlayerControls();
    _controls.Enable();
}
void Update()
{
    if (_controls.GamePlay.TakeItem.IsPressed()) Debug.Log("Is Pressed!");
}
```

[image: GamePlay/TakeItem/E]

---

### Single Action Map Event Triggered

```cs
Controls.GamePlay.Get().actionTriggered += ctx => Debug.Log(ctx.action);
```

---

### Single Action Map Direct Triggered

```cs
foreach (var _inputAction in Controls.GamePlay.Get().actions.Where(_inputAction => _inputAction.triggered))
{
    Debug.Log(_inputAction);
}
```

---

### Total Action Map Triggered

```cs
foreach (var _inputAction in Controls.asset.actionMaps.SelectMany(_assetActionMap => _assetActionMap.actions.Where(_inputAction => _inputAction.triggered)))
{
    Debug.Log(_inputAction);
}
```

Comment: I've figured it out myself and this is not what I asked, but thank you though.

Comment: @Truofan ops sorry. I read your question again. I added three methods to the answer and hope it is useful. (Note: the new input system with the event-oriented structure actually prevents over-performing. So the old way of getting the key is not very optimized.)

Comment: Thank you again, I'm using the actionTriggered event now and the rest two still look like some higher dimension alien language to me now lol, Guess it's better to stick with code that is my level.

Comment: @Truofan No, you are using the right way. Unfortunately, I misunderstood your question the first time, otherwise I could have helped better.